# Updating form values and stop submitting it

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an HTML code:

```
<form action="?" id="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return g.submitForm();">
    <input type="text" name="posX" id="formPosX" />
    <input type="text" name="posY" id="formPosY" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and JS code:

```
var g = {
    submitForm: function () {
        var form = document.forms.form1;
        if ( form.posX.value > 100 )
        {
            form.posX.value = 100;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this form is always sending after updating values. My goal is to update wrong values and stop submitting form (I'd like to do it via AJAX). When I remove the IF statement then code works fine, but I need to update some values (and also show an error, if is).

Hope you'll understand my very bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming the value in the form input is an integer, when in reality it will be treated as a string data type. Try converting the value to a number before applying the comparison.

```
    if ( parseInt(form.posX.value) > 100 )
    {
        form.posX.value = "100";
    }
```

I've adapted your code see below (You will need to include the Jquery library):

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/boggey79/kN49d/

Answer (score 0):

Form request stopped, because onSubmit return false. You need return true.

Check input value on keypress event:

```
<script>
   function checkPosX(this) {
       if ( parseInt(this.value) > 100 ) {
           this.value = "100";
       }
   }
</script>

 <form action="?" id="form1" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="posX" id="formPosX" onkeypress="checkPosX(this)" />
    <input type="text" name="posY" id="formPosY" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
```

Then work fine.